# Fullcalendar.io getEvent by date, or by extended property

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Is there a way to find all recently-added events in the local memory using the default object property names, extended properties, or events on a specific date?

`calendar.getEvents()` gets *everything* `calendar.getEventById()` gets only specific IDs.  Is it my job to filter that returned array?

Is it better to add user-created events to a different Event Source.... and use THAT source when constructing an object for the server?

How do I find all newly created events added by the user?  And, how do I get all events for a specific date?

Comment: I would either send each new event to the server as soon as you create it, or go with your idea of using a separate event source to store them before uploading.